# Problems with TEZBOZ while transferring from KT address to manager address tz

Tags: tezbox, xtz, fundraiser

I'm trying to transfer all XTZ from KT address because of the address I was delegating to is not baking anymore, it appears.

But I cannot send the XTZ to the manager tz1 address.

I have 33 XTZ in the manager tz1 address.

Also tried to send 1 XTZ to another tz1 address (funded with 10 XTZ) and get the same problem.

I tried to use Galleon wallet, but the transactions are never recorded in the blockchain.

Did I lose all my XTZ and money invested in fundraising?

[image]

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix this. I bought 3 XTZ (using exodus exchange) and sent it to the fundraiser address, then sent 1 XTZ to the KT1 address. After that, I was able to withdraw all XTZ

Comment: Tezbox is not properly maintained at this point, please move to alternative wallets available